# nvim in macOS Terminal breaks on displaying termguicolors

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, iterm2, neovim

I have been using Neovim in iTerm2 so far and it displays my Vim syntax just fine. 
I started to use the good ol' Mac OS Terminal and it cannot display my Vim syntax colors after using `set termguicolors`.

On the left side I have iTerm and on the right side is the OSX Terminal with the standard nvim highlighting.
[image]

After turning on `termguicolors` it looks like this: (iTerm works as expected and OSX Terminal presents a gray mess)
[image]

I would like to understand why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal.app only supports 256 colors, which is not the 24-bit color that truecolors uses.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. Is there a way to fix that in Terminal.app?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Not until Apple releases updates. But since I'm in `tmux` most of the time anyway, I don't really miss it. 256 colors is enough for me /shrug YMMV. I just don't use `termguicolors`

Comment: Too bad! How can it then be that in tmux the `termguicolors` displaying works in Terminal.app?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that in tmux I’m limited to 256 either way, so I dont miss that Terminal.app doesnt support more. @Tillus

Comment: Oh ok. Interestingly enough in tmux the colors are displayed correctly. Maybe I just use tmux as well as a quick fix :)