# How can I use iterm as default terminal on macOS?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, iterm2

I want to make iTerm2 as my default terminal on macOS,

I open iTerm2 and hit to `make iTerm default Term`

But it's not working!

And I go to default terminal preferences

[image: TE]

But after open it I see this
[image: err]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to rebuild your macOS' `LaunchServices`.

To do this, download [OnyX](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and choose the version based on your current macOS version.

The option that you need is in the red box, and I'd suggest that you UNCHECK anything that you don't need or don't know; otherwise, you might end up with deleting data that you might need:

[image: Onyx Illistration]

After that, you can try again with the built-in `Make iTerm2 Default Term` option in iTerm2 (if this option is greyed out for you, click `option` + the iTerm menu button to re-enable it again).

There are ways to do this through the command line without downloading third-party apps, but I trust OnyX enough to hand it the job.

However, if you decide to do it from the command line, make sure you type the command that corresponds to your current macOS version. More on that [here](https://blog.macsales.com/47158-launch-services-keeping-apps-and-file-associations-straight/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I install OnyX and it's by default checked the red box, but when i go to iTerm to a built-in option, it's already clicked "I can't enable it again", and sadly not work :(

Comment: Delete iTerm2 settings using `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2` then use AppClener to uninstall iTerm2 and try again https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner (make sure to uninstall all its related files and folders)

Comment: Do you mean to run this as a command in terminal `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2`?

Comment: Yes. It's taken from the iTerm2 FAQ https://www.iterm2.com/faq.html

Comment: sadly not work :( So can I make a shortcut for [this](https://i.imgur.com/DHge05z.png)?

Comment: I found a way to "un-grey" the "Make iTerm2 default Term" option. Click and hold `option` i.e. `alt` on the keyboard and click the iTerm2 menu button; this should make you able to select that option again. Sorry for making you go through all that trouble of uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: it's un-grey it but after making iTerm as default, it now works as default :D

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I edited the answer to include this step

Comment: I couldn't find `"Make iTerm2 default Term"` where does it exist?

Comment: I couldn't find `"Make iTerm2 default Term"` instead it says `Make Terminal default`

Answer (score 78):

(Open iTerm Build version 3.3.7)

Menu: `iTerm2` > `Make iTerm2 Default Term`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this location instead:

```
/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2
```

but note that it will not solve your issue completely. `Termianal` will start anyway, but this time, it will run `iTerm2` - as you instructed it to do.

Comment: Yup, it's Open iTerm but in general, not for a specific file/folder i want to run on it

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is find the file that opens a terminal (in my case it was metro opening in a React Native app). Find the file in your finder, right click on it, choose get info, then expand the Open With tab. There you should find a dropdown menu on what to open those kind of files with. The default is terminal, but choose iTerm2 and click on change all.

For example, in my situation I had to find launchPackager.command file under node_modules/react-native/scripts/. Do the above with that file and it will make iTerm your default terminal after clicking change all.

Answer (score 0):

From where do you want to open the terminal? I was facing the same problem as you when I wanted to open the external terminal from Visual Studio Code.
I solved it by going to <kbd>Code</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd>. Look for `terminal` in the search bar and setting `/Applications/iTerm.app` in <kbd>Terminal</kbd> > <kbd>External</kbd> for your operating system.

Comment: For me `/Applications/iTerm.app` didn't work, but just `iTerm.app` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question regarding changing the default terminal due to the builtin terminal not supporting true colors. (More info about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674310/nvim-in-macos-terminal-breaks-on-displaying-termguicolors))

I was able to reroute my terminal application by providing a startup script from the terminal preferences under the profile section to launch my alternative terminal application.

```
#! /bin/zsh
open -a Hyper.app . && killall Terminal
```

This script will terminate the terminal only if the hyper terminal was able to be opened. By having this logic on an external script, your able to open the default terminal by just commenting the line if needed as a safety precaution.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

## Set as default terminal

To set **iTerm2** as the default terminal on macOS, you can do the following:

1. Find a file in Finder
2. Right-click on it
3. Select Get Info
4. Expand the Open With tab
5. Choose iTerm2 from the dropdown menu
6. Click Change All

## Terminal to open iTerm2

To open **iTerm2** when you try to open default Terminal app on macOS, you have to do the following:

1. Create a bash file called `open_iterm.sh` in your desirable directory and insert following code.

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   # Update your path variable here.
   iterm_path="/Applications/iTerm.app"

   # Check if iTerm2 exists
   if [ -e "$iterm_path" ]; then
       # Open iTerm2
       open "$iterm_path"

       # Close the current Terminal app
       osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit'
   else
       echo "iTerm2 not found. Continuing with the current Terminal."
   fi
   ```
2. In the macOS Terminal app, select Terminal > Settings
3. Click General
4. Next to Shells open with, select Command (complete path)
5. Enter the complete path to the `open_iterm.sh` file