Howto Specify the Terminal XCode is opening when running a project
I'm developing a modern command line tool that uses some of the new image in console window features and must use a different app then the default "Terminal.App" when testing my code in the XCode IDE.
While the Scheme -> Run -> Options let me select that a terminal is used i can't find a way to specify which one (i prefer Kitty at the moment). Is there some hack to change it, either just for xcode or even system wide would be acceptable.

Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60210024/how-can-i-use-iterm-as-default-terminal-on-macos

Yes this question is part of the workaround but not the original intend and no other question is targeting the xcode specifics yet. So i would like to let the question open.
